# Need better option when trying to restore from the recycle bin

Tags: python, subprocess, bin, recycle

This is the code I have now. This goes through the explorer. But I need a better option.

```
o = win32com.client.Dispatch("WScript.Shell")
        #o.SendKeys("#m")
        #time.sleep(5)
        import subprocess as sp
        p = sp.Popen(args='c:\\windows\\explorer.exe')
        #o.AppActivate("Recycle Bin")
        time.sleep(5)
        o.SendKeys("^z", 0)
        o.SendKeys("{ENTER}", 0)
        # wait for undo to finish
        time.sleep(10)
        o.SendKeys("%{F4}", 0)
        self.Pass('Undo deletion of %s to recycle bin')
        #
        self.Log("Finished")
```

Comment: What do you mean by "better"?  What's wrong with your current approach?

Comment: This gets weird on windows 8 and 8.1. And the machines in running on are very very slow. So if explorer pops up and it takes too long and I hit the ctrl z it just doesn't work.